# Docker Configuration in the 4.7.2 Framework Project Sample Image with Expatiation

Tags: docker, frameworks

I will Create a New Project in the Azure Function App using Visual Studio 2017 Created Some Function Also And Thats Working Fine 
Now , I need to Configure the Docker to this Project.I need Sample Docker Image with Explanation Supported .Net Framework 4.7.2 Version 
.Net Core Supported and working Fine but some system dll in the framework got Error 
Error Message

```
Could not load type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The higher version of the not supported.Some dll is missing to load 
my Application current version is

Install-Package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions -Version 1.0.13